# git submodule init only repos in .gitmodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

We have a (ok, multiple) superproject that has multiple submodules that are added at different points in the non-linear history. We also have some automated processes that need to run at different commits in the superproject. Our current process clones the superproject (if needed), checks out a commit (headless), and has to make sure the submodules are reset and cleaned to their correct state. The obvious method would be to use

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

but due to the fact that the `.gitmodules` files reflect the submodules relevant for the given commits that often exits with a non-zero code with messages like:

> fatal: no submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'whatever'

The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) for `update` seems to indicate that I shouldn't get that:

> Update the registered submodules to match what the superproject expects by cloning missing submodules, fetching missing commits in submodules and updating the working tree of the submodules.

whereas the section about `foreach` mentions the `.gitmodules` file explicitly possibly indicating that I could sidestep the "missing" entry with thing like:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive 'echo $sm_path'
```

but even there I get errors like:

> fatal: No url found for submodule path 'whatever' in .gitmodules

### TL;DR

How can I run a recursive `git submodule update --init` **only** on the submodules listed in the commits `.gitmodules` files?

Notes:

> ```
> $ git --version  
> git version 2.31.1.windows.1
> ```

Comment: I suspect you checked out a rather old commit where `.gitmodules` and `.git/config` differ significantly; most probably in the `HEAD` commit there is a submodule registered in `.git/config` which is not in the old commit. I don't know of any simple way to sync the old `.gitmodules` to `.git/config`; my advice is to write code that lists submodules registered in `.git/config`, finds it in `.gitmodules` and removes from  `.git/config` if not found in `.gitmodules`.

Comment: @phd It's anywhere where `.gitmodules` and `.git/config` differ. It happens. As I mentioned, the history isn't linear, so any two branches that differ will raise this issue. I was hoping to avoid an additional script, assuming I can do it with native git commands.

Comment: Does `git submodule sync` help? I'm not sure it can remove URLs.

Comment: Don't think so. That would just replace the urls in the `.git/config` files, no?

Comment: That's why I said "*I don't know of any simple way to sync the old `.gitmodules` to `.git/config`*". PS. I have a repo with a rather complex submodules tree; I'll try to experiment on it…

Comment: Well, unused submodules in `.git/config` don't seem to be relevant, `git submodule` ignores them so my initial idea is wrong.

Comment: The submodule support in Git is kind of a mess. In general *extra* modules don't hurt (as @phd noted) but *missing* ones do, and switching around from commit to commit where modules shift in and out of existence in the various commits causes heartache because Git doesn't clean out unwanted submodules from the working tree, nor add missing submodules unless the checkout uses `--recursive`, which is too big a hammer, etc. How to get *out* of this mess is not clear.